# Folder Transferred from SSD to HDD is not showing after reboot

Tags: dual-boot, windows, filesystem, ntfs

I moved the 18gb folder from my SSD to HDD. After the successful transfer I even open the files, but once I reboot the system that folder disappeared. I even checked the total size of the drive it has 18extra used space but it's not visible. I'm using dual boot , windows 11 and Linux, this happened when I opened windows and returned back to Linux, can someone help me to get back that folder

Comment: Is the filesystem on the HDD NTFS? Did you hibernate Windows or is fast restart/fast boot enabled on the Windows OS?

Comment: Yes it's NTFS, and I already turned off fast restart. Once I even opened the files in that folder after transfer. So I sure that transfer was successful. I even checked trash and even tried recovering. But there was no clue about that folder. But it used tha space from drive

Comment: Have you  turned off fast restart before or after copying? and did you shut down Windows completely before copying or hibernated it?

Comment: Turned off before copying, My HDD is common for both Linux and Windows but SSD is parted one for only Linux another only for windows ( different filesystem). After copying from SSD in Linux to HDD in Linux, I open it in Linux itself and it was there , and I restarted the system ( not shutdown) and booted windows ( first priority). There it was not available...all others folders were there except the new one.

Comment: Is NTFS compression enabled on Windows for the filesystem on HDD by any chance? Did Windows offer a disk check when you restarted into Windows after the copying? ... Meanwhile, if that folder is important to you, I would advise against running any recovery or fixing tool on the filesystem at this stage.

Comment: Proper handling of disks in both Linux and Windows includes the use of Eject (Windows) and unmounting in Linux; always wait until you get confirmation (Windows) and the bash prompt back (or disk disappears from Nautilus) - this kind of trouble will eventually happen if you don't.